# JDBC cannot be resolved to a variable in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, classpath

Currently trying to use a `sqlite-dbc4-3.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` that was given to me as part of an assignment. I've tried running my main file and I get the errors below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    org.sqlite.JDBC cannot be resolved to a variable

    at DbBasic.open(DbBasic.java:54)
    at DbBasic.<init>(DbBasic.java:67)
    at DbUser.<init>(DbUser.java:40)
    at Main.go(Main.java:12)
    at Main.main(Main.java:65)
```

Here's part of the `DbBasic` class that attempts to connect and open a database using JDBC:

```
  private Connection getConnection()
  // get the connection
  {
    Connection con = null;
    try {

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLITE_DATABASE_LOCATION+dbName);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
      notify("Db.getConnection database location ["+SQLITE_DATABASE_LOCATION+"] db name["+dbName+"]", sqle);
    };
    return con;
  } // end of method "getConnection"

  private void open()
  // "open" the database : actually really setting up the connection and obtaining the metadata about the server
    // makes sure that database file is present before trying to establish connection
    // otherwise SQLite will create a new, empty database with the name provided
  {
    File dbf = new File(dbName);
    if (dbf.exists() == false)
    {
        System.out.println("SQLite database file ["+dbName+"] does not exist");
        System.exit(0);
    };

    try {

        Class.forName(org.sqlite.JDBC);
        con  = getConnection();
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException cnfe ) {
      notify("Db.Open",cnfe);
    };
    if (debug) System.out.println("Db.Open : leaving");
  } // end of constructor "Open"
```

I have already tried adding external JAR's and the .jar file is then added to my 'Referenced Libraries' in Eclipse.

I'm having trouble understanding the `Class.forName(org.sqlite.JDBC)` and how to make it work with my .jar file

Comment: How are you building your project ? You need to use a maven or ant build to setup your project with your dependencies.

Comment: I've set Eclipse to 'Build Automatically'

Comment: That not the answer to my question read on maven build. You need to use that to build your project.

Comment: Class.forName() takes a String argument, try Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); (with the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Though the post is relatively old and the OP might not be interested in a solution for this issue now anymore, thought of putting this as an answer. It might help someone who runs into such silly issues. This is one of the common mistakes that people do while using Eclipse as an IDE, try to run code that doesn't even compile.

You can check the "Problems" view in Eclipse and fix the compilation errors and then try to compile your program. The obvious error here on this question is the missing double quotes `""` while using the driver name.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```